# How do I remove this background when hovering over navigation bar links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

There's this ugly gray color background when I over a link in the navigation bar.
How can I remove this gray background. The links should remain red and when hovered over, it should have been yellow on the overall black background but there's a gray background over that link. Also in the pills. I think the background appears  whenever it's over something that is associated with 'nav' word cause other links look fine. Only the navigation bar and the pills cause its css is nav-pills apparently. Attaching images of what happens when I hover over it.
p.s - adding dot instead of.com because I have less than 10 reputation and cannot post more than 2 links.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBPzV.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZoJP.jpg

```css
#mainNav .container{
    padding:0
}
#mainNav .container .navbar-brand{
    color:#fed136;font-family:"Kaushan Script","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,cursive
}
#mainNav .container .navbar-brand.active,#mainNav .container .navbar-brand:active,#mainNav .container .navbar-brand:focus,#mainNav .container .navbar-brand:hover{
    color:#fec503
}
#mainNav .container .btn-toggle{
    padding:.75em;font-size:80%
}
#mainNav .container .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link{
    font-size:90%;padding:.75em 0;font-family:Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:1px;color:red
}
#mainNav .container .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.active,#mainNav .container .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover{
    color:#fed136
}
@media (min-width:768px){
    #mainNav{
        background-color:transparent;padding:25px 0;-webkit-transition:padding .3s;-moz-transition:padding .3s;transition:padding .3s;border:none
    }
    #mainNav .navbar-brand{
        font-size:1.75em;-webkit-transition:all .3s;-moz-transition:all .3s;transition:all .3s
    }
    #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link{
        padding:1.2em .4em!important
    }
    #mainNav.navbar-shrink{
        background-color:#222;padding:5px 0
    }
    #mainNav.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand{
        padding:.65em 0;font-size:1.25em
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Demo</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-toggle hidden-md-up float-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            <!-- Navigation Bar List Contents -->
            <div class="clearfix hidden-md-up"></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-md-right">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#about">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#sample">Sample Article</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#topics">Topics</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#whyus">Why Choose Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="form.php" class="btn btn-md btn-info btn-block" role="button">Order now</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: edit your question , provide a snippt

Comment: Your question does not provide enough code to reproduce the problem. Please update your question so that it shows all your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited your image links & code, but the output does not seem to match with your images. Did you forget to mention some CSS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of Bootstrap `CSS` code. There is this code on `hover`:

```
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Remove the background color and it should do the trick.

In the next working snippet I set it to `transparent` by strengthening the selector:

```css
.container .nav > li > a:focus,
.container .nav > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
#mainNav .container {
  padding: 0
}
#mainNav .container .navbar-brand {
  color: #fed136;
  font-family: "Kaushan Script", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, cursive
}
#mainNav .container .navbar-brand.active,
#mainNav .container .navbar-brand:active,
#mainNav .container .navbar-brand:focus,
#mainNav .container .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #fec503
}
#mainNav .container .btn-toggle {
  padding: .75em;
  font-size: 80%
}
#mainNav .container .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: .75em 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: red
}
#mainNav .container .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.active,
#mainNav .container .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fed136
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #mainNav {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 25px 0;
    -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
    -moz-transition: padding .3s;
    transition: padding .3s;
    border: none
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.75em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    padding: 1.2em .4em!important
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink {
    background-color: #f00;
    padding: 5px 0
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
    padding: .65em 0;
    font-size: 1.25em
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Demo</a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-toggle hidden-md-up float-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <!-- Navigation Bar List Contents -->
    <div class="clearfix hidden-md-up"></div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-md-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#about">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#sample">Sample Article</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#topics">Topics</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#whyus">Why Choose Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="form.php" class="btn btn-md btn-info btn-block" role="button">Order now</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way that you can do it is to open the page with firefox or chrome Browser and right click the portion that you want there a pop-up appear choose Inspect Element there a bunch of code appears.

On that left side shows the HTML and the right side part shows the css there you can change and see the difference as a live one.

**Important** thing is that copy the code form the part that you change and paste it in your code then only it works.